# How to align two commandButtons inside a form

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have two `<p:commandButton>` elements inside `<h:form>` in my .xhtml page.
How to align them center?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a div or span content and text-align: center that div.

```
<div class="form-group center">
  <p:commandButton value="C1" action="#{login.login}" />
  <p:commandButton value="C2" action="#{login.login}" />
</div>
<style>
  .center {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

There are many many ways to achieve this, and maybe looking into CSS could help understand it a bit more.

Helpful link: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#block